# How to dynamic cast from base to child class when the child is stored on a vector of base pointers

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism, c++14, dispatch

I have shared pointers of **Child** objects stored in a **Vector of Base shared pointers** and I need to dynamically cast the elements of the *Base vector to its Child type*, such that I can **invoke function with *Child specific signature***.

An example follows below. The first code block defines the class hierarchy and the "identify" functions that I would like to use. The second code block gives a specific example of how **I want to invoke a TYPE-specific "identify" function**, given that I can cast the original object type from the Base class to a Child class (e.g. A,B,C).

Is there any pattern or technique that I can tackle this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base {};
class A : public Base{};
class B : public Base{};
class C : public Base{};

class CollectionOfBase
{
public:
    void add (std::shared_ptr<Base> item){m_items.push_back(item);}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> const& getItems() const {return m_items;}

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> m_items;
};

// I want to use these 3 functions instead of identify( std::shared_ptr<Base> const& )
void identify( std::shared_ptr<A> const& )
{
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}
void identify( std::shared_ptr<B> const& )
{
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}
void identify( std::shared_ptr<C> const& )
{
    std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
}

//This function works in the below for loop, but this is not what I need to use
void identify( std::shared_ptr<Base> const& )
{
    std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
}
```

Below, you can find the second code block:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    CollectionOfBase collection;

    collection.add(make_shared<A>());
    collection.add(make_shared<A>());
    collection.add(make_shared<C>());
    collection.add(make_shared<B>());

    for (auto const& x : collection.getItems())
    {
        // THE QUESTION:
        // How to distinguish different type of items
        // to invoke "identify" with object specific signatures (e.g. A,B,C) ???
        // Can I cast somehow the object types that I push_back on my Collection ???
        // Note that this loop does not know the add order AACB that we pushed the Child pointers.

        identify(x);
    }
    /*
    The desired output of this loop should be:

    A
    A
    C
    B

    */

    return 0;
}
```

The code is also available on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/xjCwPI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three approaches you could take here: OO and dynamic dispatch, visitor, and variant. Whichever one is better is going to depend on how many *types* you have and how many *operations* you have - as well as which one you're more likely to add to.

1. Actually use OO. If you need each derived object to perform some operation in a different way, the way to do that in OO is to add a virtual member function:

   ```
   struct Base { virtual const char* name() = 0; };
   struct A : Base { const char* name() override { return "A"; }
   // ...

   for (auto const& x : collection.getItems()) {
       std::cout << x->name() << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. Use the visitor pattern. This is halfway between OO and functional - we create a base object that knows how to interact with all the types:

   ```
   struct Visitor;
   struct Base { virtual void visit(Visitor& ) = 0; };
   struct A;
   struct B;
   struct C;

   struct Visitor {
       virtual void visit(A& ) = 0;
       virtual void visit(B& ) = 0;
       virtual void visit(C& ) = 0;
   };

   struct A : Base { void visit(Visitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); } };
   // ...

   struct IdentityVisitor : Visitor {
       void visit(A& ) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
       void visit(B& ) { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
       void visit(C& ) { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
   };

   IdentityVisitor iv;
   for (auto const& x : collection.getItems()) {
       x->visit(iv);
   }
   ```
3. Just use a variant. Instead of storing a collection of `shared_ptr<Base>`, store a collection of `variant<A,B,C>` where those types aren't even in a hierarchy. They're just three arbitrary types. And then:

   ```
   for (auto const& x : collection.getItems()) {
       visit(overload(
           [](A const& ){ std::cout << "A" << std::endl; },
           [](B const& ){ std::cout << "B" << std::endl; },
           [](C const& ){ std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
           ), x);
   }
   ```

Comment: I guess your third approach is a "smarter" implementation for the visitor pattern.

Comment: @csguth It's just the difference between static visitation and dynamic visitation. There's advantages and disadvantages to both, I don't know that one is strictly better. Certainly if you have a million types but only a small number of operations, both aren't great.

Answer (score 2):

[Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) solves the problem.

Basically, add a virtual method `Base::accept(Visitor& v)`.

Each child will override such method calling `v.visit(*this)`.

Your visitor class should look like this:

```
class Visitor
{
public:
  void visit(A&) { /* this is A */ }
  void visit(B&) { /* this is B */ }
  void visit(C&) { /* this is C */ }
}
```

Instantiate your visitor: `Visitor v;`

Iterate on your vector calling `x->accept(v);`.

http://ideone.com/2oT5S2

Answer (score 1):

@Barry and @csguth thank you both for your answers.

The 3rd option of Barry is very interesting and I would like to give it a try. A working example with **boost::static_visitor** and **boost::variant** can be found on this **[page](http://www.baryudin.com/blog/boost-variant-and-lambda-functions-c-11.html)**.

In my case, I did not consider OO and virtual methods as I want to avoid putting logic into these A,B,C objects. With respect to the visitor pattern, it was the only good option that I had in mind. However, I was hoping to discover some more flexible solution like the "LambdaVisitor" and thank you for opening up my eyes!